# Control on a tabpage

Tags: c#, .net, controls

Why the control.OnHandleDestroyed() is not called when the parent TabPage is removed using the tabControl1.RemoveAt() call?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be Dispose is not called on removed TabPages..You can add

```
Dispose();
```

or

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

after removing to force garbage collector run its cycle.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I am trying to understand the reason not to find a workaround.